# Position figure to absolute middle in multirow

Tags: tables, floats

I have two problems with my multirow:

1. I want the figures to position to absolute middle of the multirow, so the margin is equally big.
2. There are small gaps in the mulitrow cells where new rows are added, the red circle indicates one of the gaps.

The source:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} \hline
        \textbf{Exercise name} & Cable Crossover & \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[height=32mm]{images/exercise/132_1.jpg}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[height=32mm]{images/exercise/1.png}} \\ 
        \hhline{--~~}
        \textbf{Exercise type} & Strength & & \\ 
        \hhline{--~~}
        \textbf{Muscle}       & Chest & & \\ 
        \hhline{--~~}
        \textbf{Other muscles}  & Shoulders & & \\ 
        \hhline{--~~}
        \textbf{Equipment}    & Cable & & \\  
        \hhline{--~~}
        \textbf{Mechanic}     & Isolation & & \\ 
        \hhline{--~~}
        \textbf{Body area}    & Upper body & &\\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Exercise example based on Cable Crossover.}
    \label{table:exercise_example_chest}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: As to adding gap above the figure, one option is `\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newcommand\xincludegraphics[2][]{\addvbuffer[3pt 3pt]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}` and then invoke the figures with `\xincludegraphics`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, that did the trick. Now i only need to figure out the strange gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gaps in the rows appear because you have specified gaps in those positions

```
 \hhline{--~~}
```

You want

```
 \hhline{--~|~|}
```

or arguably

```
\hhline{|-|-|~|~|}
```

although the `-` will expand to fill the rule position if you don't specify `|` in the first two columns, so the difference there is less.

For adjusting the image position I'd just use

```
\raisebox{-5pt}{\includegraphics{...}}
```

using whatever value looks right.

Comment: Using `[-0.667ex]` as the optional correction in `\multirow` seems correct, and it presumably will remain so in case of font changes (size, family, &c.).